# JQueryMobile Datebox - link without input box

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I'm looking to have a small cal icon (or the one embedded in input box) when clicked has the standard behavior of "popup calendar" and upon selection fires onClick event or function.

The basic calendar is:

```
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="date box" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}'>
```

I would like it to only be an icon in the right side of the header. Here is my existing header code that has a "+" as a link to OnClick event.

```
<div data-role="header" class="tb">
    <h1>MyDate</h1>
    <a class="ui-btn-right" id="myplus" onclick="openPickDate();">+</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Here is a jsFiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LS3g6/1/**

---

The HTML markup to include a hidden datebox in the header with a button at top right is as follows:

```
<div data-role="header">
   <h1>My page</h1> 
   <a  data-role="button" id="myplus" class="ui-btn-right" >+</a>
   <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "hideInput": "true", "centerHoriz": "true", "closeCallback":"onCLoseMyDate();"}' />
</div>
```

Setting hideInput to true hides the calendar input box, centerHoriz centers the popup on the screen and the closeCallback is called when you select a date and close the popup.

To launch the popup, handle the click event on the myplus button:

```
$('#myplus').on('click', function() {
    $('#mydate').datebox('open');
});
```

Then supply the callback function:

```
function onCLoseMyDate(){
    var dateObject = $('#mydate').datebox('getTheDate');
    alert(dateObject);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried the jSFiddle link and the example is not working?

Comment: What browser are you using? I am using Chrome stable on Win7 and the fiddle works for me...

Comment: safari and I tried Firefox, no go… could it be the datebox links are not in there?

Comment: sorry, working fine… link is sitting over JSFiddle reload link and caused an issue… thanks this is what I needed.

Comment: I'm having a problem in my actual code: the click event is firing but no calendar? i've set an alert that works fine but cal never shows? `$('#myplus').on('click', function() {
     $('#mydate').datebox('open');
     //alert("you clicked +");
 });
` I did but the input inside the h1 tag but tried it in fiddle and works fine

Comment: Part of the fix is: I was assigning text to the h1 tag, once I removed this the cal works, but now I can't put anything in the H1 text? If I move the input box outside the H1 my button vanishes?

Comment: i am not seeing this in the fiddle so it is hard to say what is going on. How about surrounding the input with a div set to display: none. See my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LS3g6/4/

Comment: That works with static text, but not for dynamic… I'm setting h1 with `$('#roster h1').text(rdate);` and this breaks it. - Also can.t seem to format the datebox date to mm/dd/YYYY ?

Comment: Instead of setting the h1 text, put and empty <span> inside the h1 and set its text or html $('#roster h1 > span').html(rdate). That way it should leave the datebox alone.  Have you tried the dateFormat option.

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LS3g6/5/ with the dynamic text in the span.

Comment: I have tried ever dateFormat I can find, nothing works, from what I have found the dateFormat is ver 1 and the overrideDateFormat is ver 2, but nether one works for me?